# How do I apply a several classes to div using ngClass?

Tags: angular

How do I apply a several classes to div?

```
<div class="al-timeline"
         [ngClass]="{'right': isDisplayRight, 'remove-circle': !timelineData.date, 'first-circle': isFirstItem, isLastItem ? 'arrow' ? isDisplayRight: 'arrow-left' : 'arrow-right'}">
</div>
    &.arrow {
    &::after {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 49%;
        bottom: -9px;
    }

    &.arrow-right {
        &::after {
            border-left: 20px solid @al-main-color-2;
        }
    }

    &.arrow-left {
        &::after {
            border-right: 20px solid @al-main-color-2;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to apply 'arrow' class if `isLastItem`, and if arrow class is applied, I want to add 'arrow-left' class if `isDisplayRight` else add 'arrow-right'

Answer (score 1):

club the both conditions for second class

apply `arrow-right` if `(isLastItem && isDisplayRight)` condition is true

Comment: I updated my question, in this case I should rewrite my styles and 'arrow-right' and 'arrow-left' will have the same properties except border

Comment: I did so:
`'arrow arrow-left' : (isLastItem && isDisplayRight), 'arrow arrow-right' : (isLastItem && !isDisplayRight)`
but i don't really like

Comment: Oh, unfortunately it doesn't work, it works only in this case: 
  `'arrow arrow-left' : (isLastItem && isDisplayRight)`

Comment: add separate for arrow : `'arrow: isLastItem, 'arrow-left' : (isLastItem && isDisplayRight), 'arrow-right' : (isLastItem && !isDisplayRight)`